# How I can add atrribute to Laravel model collection?

Tags: sql, database, laravel, eloquent

I have Collection of Category.

with `App\Category::all()` I get:

`ID | PARENT_ID | NAME    | DEPTH'`

`1  |         0 | parent1 | 0`

`2  |         0 | parent2 | 0`

`3  |         1 | child1  | 1`

`4  |         2 | child2  | 1`

How I can add custom atrribute (column or method results) to my collection?
The result I wanna get when I write etc: `$categories=Category::with('childs');`

`ID| PARENT_ID | NAME    | DEPTH' | CHILDS`

`1 | 0         | parent1 | 0      | {2 | 1 | child1 | 1 | NULL}`

`2 | 0         | parent2 | 0      | {3 | 2 | child2 | 1 | NULL}`

`3 | 1         | child1  | 1      | NULL`

`4 | 2         | child2  | 1      | NULL`

I think you get the idea. I tried use Accessors & Mutators and I successfully added attribute with data etc.

> $category->childs; // value should be  {12 | 10 | name1 | 1 | NULL}

but I'm stuck because I can't pass data to method with queried data and return it back. I want to use one table, later I will add `left` and `right` columns to table to have tree database, now I'm just trying a little simpler - have parent and add children to it's collection

Comment: I actualy don't fully get your question. Do you want to add an attribute to the elements of the collection? The data that you need to mass to the method is.. what?

Comment: What do you mean with this: `I can't pass data to method with queried data and return it back`. Please, provide the method that you mentioned.

Comment: It is a little confusing what you want. Maybe explain better your current approach, your current result and your expected result.

Comment: Show your code, please. In general, iterate all collection items and add attribute you want

Comment: I am not entirely, but maybe appends attribute is what you are looking for.
https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-serialization#appending-values-to-json

Comment: Sorry for my English, it is difficult to me clearly express myself. The guy below got the idea. Thanks for effort

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use model [relationship](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#introduction) to itself:

Category.php

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Category extends Model
{
    protected $with = ['childs'];

    public function childs()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Category::class, 'parent_id');
    }
}
```

CategoryController.php

```
public function index()
{
    $categories = Category::all();

    return $categories;
}
```

`$categories` will return result as you need:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "parent_id": 0,
    "name": "parent1",
    "depth": 0,
    "childs": [
      {
        "id": 3,
        "parent_id": 1,
        "name": "child1",
        "depth": 0,
        "childs": []
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "parent_id": 0,
    "name": "parent2",
    "depth": 0,
    "childs": [
      {
        "id": 4,
        "parent_id": 2,
        "name": "child2",
        "depth": 0,
        "childs": []
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "parent_id": 1,
    "name": "child1",
    "depth": 0,
    "childs": []
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "parent_id": 2,
    "name": "child2",
    "depth": 0,
    "childs": []
  }
]
```